# Word or phrase for the action of being awake or asleep

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm not sure how to phrase this question exactly, but I came up with an analogy:

If I am at home, or at work, or at the beach, that is my location. I am located at home, etc. Likewise, if I am asleep or awake, that is my _____?  Then I am _____ asleep?

Is there a word or phrase that would make sense for that usage? Or am I looking for something that doesn't exist?

Comment: *State of consciousness* would cover both cases, awake or asleep.

Comment: Indeed, but in that case it would be better if we used the words conscious and unconscious instead of awake and asleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first blank, I'd say you can use "state of wakefulness". As for the second blank, it would be blank, since "asleep" is an adjective.

However, if we were to say it in a different way, I would say that:

I am in a state of sleep. 

OR

I am in a state of wakefulness.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I'm using this for a variable name, and WakefulState is much better than what I had. Sometimes naming things is the hardest part of writing code.

Comment: Hahaha! As a programmer myself, I feel you. Some days you just don't care about variable names, and when you get back to them later you wonder what they were for. :P